# Byzantine's General

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-transactions

So I was reading Lamport's paper on Byzantine Generals in which he proves that for T malicious generals you need 2T+1 generals in a group to read a consensus. However I dont understand how. If there are T malicious nodes making up stuff, you just need T+1 votes to outvote them. Why is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

There is [a section on Wikipedia about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance#Early_solutions):

> One solution considers scenarios in which messages may be forged, but which will be Byzantine-fault-tolerant as long as the number of traitorous generals does not equal or exceed one third. **The impossibility of dealing with one-third or more traitors ultimately reduces to proving that the 1 Commander + 2 Lieutenants problem cannot be solved, if the Commander is traitorous.** The reason is, if we have three commanders, A, B, and C, and A is the traitor: when A tells B to attack and C to retreat, and B and C send messages to each other, forwarding A's message, neither B nor C can figure out who is the traitor, since it isn't necessarily A – the other commander could have forged the message purportedly from A. It can be shown that if n is the number of generals in total, and t is the number of traitors in that n, then there are solutions to the problem only when n is greater than or equal to 3t + 1

Comment: Yeah Lamport's paper shows that we can reduce the problem of fewer than 3m general's where m is the number of malicious generals to a 3 general's problem and hence show it is impossible to reach a consensus in that case. However that still doesnt make sense to me and also I dont understand why majority voting won't work. Suppose there are 9 generals in total with 4 malicious generals and 5 good generals and the 5 good generals say "attack" whereas the rest of the 4 say "retreat". if they go by majority voting the good generals will attack which is what we want.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that the 5 good generals have a hard time to agree on "attack" when two of them have been told to "retreat" by their malicious commander.

Answer (score 0):

> you just need T+1 votes to outvote them. Why is that not the case?

This makes sense if all loyal generals produce the same answer, but that's not the case for BGP systems, where each honest element can give you a different answer.

BGP is for systems where each element sees a different information. Example: redundant radars. It is not for systems where the elements are mirrored (ex. redundant HDs).

**Example:**

- **Generals:** A, B, C;
- **Traitor:** C;
- **A** says "*attack*";
- **B** says "*retreat*";
- **C** says "*attack*" to **A**, and "*retreat*" to "**B**";
- **Result:** **A** thinks it has reached agreement and it will attack alone;